# undefined symbol in /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1 when using ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel

I frequently use ssh to a computer with redhat using the Y option so I can forward the windows. I always saw errors like this one

```
/usr/lib64/firefox/firefox: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest
```

This wasn't a problem since everything was working anyway. Now I'm trying to solve it since it's causing troubles with some other program called abaqus. this is the error message.

```
/usr/local/Abaqus/6.11-1/exec/ABQcaeK.exe: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: _XGetRequest
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nex_PrimException<ipc_IPCMsgErrorTypeEnm, 1>'
```

My knowledge of linux is just basic so I know how to use the terminal and the basic commands, but I have no clue about this kind of things.
Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this linux system have 3rd-party graphical card drivers instlaled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. One of the libraries needed to be updated. 
If you have that problem I recommend 'yum update' in the server.

Comment: Specifically, run `yum update libGL.so.1` and update that. That resolved the issue on my CentOS 6 server.

Comment: @user100022, that did the trick. Thanks!